# get the text entered in input box using java-script

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to javascript I'm trying to create a web page where we can enter
name in an input box and using javascript's alert method show an alert box which says hello and the name that we entered in the input box
    my code is

```
    //html
<input id="test" type="text" name="nm" placeholder="Enter name">
<button onclick="fun(i dont know what to pass here in order to get the text entered in that text box)" type="button" name="button">Click here</button>

   //javascript
//i tried like this...first

function fun(x) {
  alert("HELLO" + x);
}

//i tried this...then
var x = document.getElementsById("test").value; [->here i also dono what to put.]

function fun(x) {
  alert("HELLO" + x);
}
```

Comment: `.getElementsById()` is not a valid JavaScript method. You want the singular `.getElementById()`.

Comment: `<button onclick="alert('you need to do this')"` put your text in `"` quotes, that will tell the code that it's a string.

Comment: @NilsKähler i want to alert the text entered in the input box so what should i put inside the brackets i mean here...onclick="alert(here);

Comment: @Mirkhan I have edited my answer to match your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `getElementById` instead of `getElementsById`. I hope this helps, and happy learning :)

**Your code:**

```js
function fun() {
  var textInTest = document.getElementById("test").value;
  alert("Value entered" + textInTest);
}
```

```html
<input id="test" type="text" name="nm" placeholder="Enter name">
<button onclick="fun()" type="button" name="button">Click here</button>
```

Comment: Your answer is in the right direction, but missing a couple of points. First, the question asks for an `alert` not a `console.log`. Also, it was asked for a dynamic alert with the input box value, not a "predefined string". Could you please update your answer?